# Mono.defualtEmpty() vs Mono.switchIfEmpty()

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

when upper stream emit nullValue,
we can use 'Mono.defualtIfEmpty()'  or 'Mono.switchIfEmpty()' to replace null value.

But `switchIfEmpty()` evaluate upper stream value eager. So we use Mono.defer() for lazy evaluation.

1. Is 'Mono.defualtIfEmpty()' eager evaluation too? like switchIfEmpty()?
2. How to change Mono.defualtIfEmpty() to do lazy evaluation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [Mono<T> defaultIfEmpty(T defaultV)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#defaultIfEmpty-T-) use a precomputed value when the mono completes empty.
- [Mono<T> switchIfEmpty(Mono<? extends T> alternate)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#switchIfEmpty-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-) : If *and only if* the mono completes empty, then the mono passed as argument will be subscribed to.

With `defaultIfEmpty`, you must provide the fallback value on assembly, so it is necessarily eager.

As `switchIfEmpty` takes a Mono as argument, it makes it possible to use it both for eager and lazy evaluation.
Apart from cached Mono or Mono.just, most Mono objects/implementations are lazily evaluated.

In any case, the *upstream* Mono is *not* evaluated eagerly, whatever operator you choose.

The upstream mono is only evaluated upon subscription.

**Example 1** : verify that upstream is not evaluated until subscription :

```java
var upstream = Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
    System.out.println("UPSTREAM EVALUATION");
    return "upstream";
});

var defaultIfEmpty = upstream.defaultIfEmpty("default");

System.out.println("Nothing evaluated yet");
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("Still not evaluated");

defaultIfEmpty.block();
```

Output:

```
Nothing evaluated yet
Still not evaluated
UPSTREAM EVALUATION
```

**Example 2** : Check that switchIfEmpty is triggered only after upstream evaluation

```java
var upstream = Mono.fromRunnable(() -> System.out.println("UPSTREAM EVALUATION"));
var switchEmpty = upstream.switchIfEmpty(Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        System.out.println("SWITCH EVALUATED");
        return "switch";
}));

System.out.println("Nothing evaluated yet");
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("Still not evaluated");

switchEmpty.block();
```

Output:

```
Nothing evaluated yet
Still not evaluated
UPSTREAM EVALUATION
SWITCH EVALUATED
```

**Example 3** : SwitchIfEmpty is not evaluated if upstream sends a value :

```java
var upstream = Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
    System.out.println("UPSTREAM EVALUATION");
    return "upstream";
});

var switchEmpty = upstream.switchIfEmpty(Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
    System.out.println("SWITCH EVALUATED");
    return "switch";
}));

System.out.println("Nothing evaluated yet");
Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("Still not evaluated");

switchEmpty.block();
```

Output:

```
Nothing evaluated yet
Still not evaluated
UPSTREAM EVALUATION
```